# Windows Piping to a file from CMD

Tags: windows, cmd, pipe, notepad

Quick question that I couldn't find an answer to. When piping to a file as such:

```
echo "hello" > hello.txt
```

does this operation actually call notepad.exe on Windows, or is this a non application level file operation?

Comment: No, it doesn't use notepad.  (I'm not sure why you would think that it might.)  The application that writes the file is the command shell, `cmd.exe`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `echo` is a builtin command in the windows Command Prompt (`cmd.exe`) used to display/output messages.

The output redirector, `>`, followed by a file path makes `cmd.exe` write the message to that file instead of to your screen.

---

You can see the full list of builtin commands in `cmd.exe` by typing `help` at the command prompt

Comment: help also includes external commands (for example diskpart or format) and does not tell you which commands are internal or external. The list at http://ss64.com/nt/ shows both but has a `dot` character after the internal commands.

Answer (score 0):

`echo` is an **internal** command, which means it is built in to the windows command shell `cmd.exe`.

Source [Internal commands](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-internal.html):

> The Windows CMD shell CMD.exe contains a number of 'internal' commands.

...

> ASSOC, BREAK, CALL ,CD/CHDIR, CLS, COLOR, COPY, DATE, DEL, DIR, DPATH,
>   ECHO, ENDLOCAL, ERASE, EXIT, FOR, FTYPE, GOTO, IF, KEYS, MD/MKDIR,
>   MKLINK (vista and above), MOVE, PATH, PAUSE, POPD, PROMPT, PUSHD, REM,
>   REN/RENAME, RD/RMDIR, SET, SETLOCAL, SHIFT, START, TIME, TITLE, TYPE,
>   VER, VERIFY, VOL

---

Piping (a form of **redirection**) is also performed by the windows command shell `cmd.exe`.

See [Redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) for more information.

---

The means that when you execute `echo "hello" > hello.txt` the whole of the command (the echo followed by the redirection is performed by `cmd.exe`.